# Why JSON.stringify() does not return data

Tags: javascript, android, javascript-objects, stringify, zebra-scanners

In latest Zebra mobile Enterprise browser 3.3 EB Javascipt objects should dumped for informational purposes.
This is webkit based modern browser running in Android 11.

I tried to dump Log object (https://techdocs.zebra.com/enterprise-browser/3-3/api/log/) using

```
JSON.stringify(EB.Log)
```

but this outputs undefined.

Accessing object properties by name like

```
EB.Log.filePath
```

or

```
EB.Application.version
```

returns proper data.

How to dump whole object content when property names are not known, as much data as possible?

JSON.stringify() works for some Enterprise browser API (https://techdocs.zebra.com/enterprise-browser/3-3/api/) objects:

```
JSON.stringify(EB.Battery.batteryStatus({}))
JSON.stringify(EB.SignalIndicators.wlanStatus())
```

For EB.SmartCradle object getAllProperties() returns data:

```
JSON.stringify(EB.SmartCradle.getAllProperties())
```

For some objects JSON.stringify does not return data:

```
JSON.stringify(EB.Log)
JSON.stringify(EB.Application)
JSON.stringify(EB.Barcode.getSupportedProperties())
```

Using Object.getOwnPropertyNames returns undefined

```
  JSON.stringify(EB.Log, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(EB.Log))
  JSON.stringify(EB.Application, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(EB.Application))
```

Application and Log objects do not have `getAllProperties()` and `getSupportedProperties()` methods so those cannot used.

Accessing properties by name works but property names are not known and may change if Zebra changes API.

Browser console is not easily accessible in mobile browser. Object data should retrieved using javascript.

How to dump js object for informational purposes in human readable form?